# What is the difference between sealed/ covariant object and $Exact + $ReadOnly?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there any difference between:

```
type MovieType = {|
  +blob?: string,
  +name: string,
  +url?: string
|};
```

and

```
type MovieType = $Exact<$ReadOnly<{
  blob?: string,
  name: string,
  url?: string
}>>;
```

?

I am wondering if [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype) is treating objects differently depending on how they are defined or if the former is just a syntactic sugar for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Those two object types should be equivalent.

[`$ReadOnly<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) makes all the properties covariant:

> $ReadOnly is a type that represents the read-only version of a
>   given object type T. A read-only object type is an object type whose
>   keys are all read-only.
>
> This means that the following 2 types are equivalent:
>
> ```
> type ReadOnlyObj = {
>   +key: any,  // read-only field, marked by the `+` annotation
> };
>
> type ReadOnlyObj = $ReadOnly<{
>   key: any,
> }>;
> ```

[`$Exact<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-exact) takes an inexact object and makes it exact:

> $Exact<{name: string}> is a synonym for {| name: string |} as in the Object documentation.